# JSON API Error - You need to login with a user that has 'edit_posts' capacity

Tags: json, angularjs, http, wordpress

I'm building an app on angular and ionic, I'm trying to access my WordPress and create new post.

1. I've generated auth cookie using JSON API User plugin (https://wordpress.org/plugins/json-api/)
2. I've got a valid nonce to create posts.
3. I'm using all the right parameter to create new post:

   $http.post(domain+'/posts/create_post?nonce='+nonce.nonce+'&title='+title+'&content='+content+'&status='+status+'&author='+author)

But when I've tried to insert new post i get this massage:
"Error: You need to login with a user that has 'edit_posts' capacity"

i've that i need to add the cookie parameter to the header request, but i don't understand how.

Please help me to solve this :)

Comment: looks like the post author user is a subscriber. It has no permission to create a new post.

Comment: PROBABLY a subscriber. A user role can be anything, especially if he has a plugin that is messing around with user roles.

Answer (score 0):

This is about the user's role, not the the auth cookie. The auth cookie would login the user, but their roles and capabilities are stored in the database. There are many ways to change the user's role, including going into the Admin Dashboard as as admin, clicking Users, the user's name, and selecting "Editor" [or whatever is appropriate] in the drop down menu.

Comment: Actually, now that you mention it, wouldn't Wordpress throw an error about CAPABILITY not CAPACITY? I don't even know what a capacity is in Wordpress! Anyway in Wordpress a CAPABILITY is about roles, and doesn't have anything to do with the auth cookie. So I don't know what is going on here, this doesn't even seem like a Wordpress error to me. I guess that means the problem probably lies within the plugin you're using. One thing we know, the plugin author doesn't know the difference between the words capacity and capability, or at least I don't understand the context.

Answer (score 0):

For complete details, see https://wordpress.org/support/topic/error-you-need-to-login-with-a-user-that-has-edit_posts-capacity.

But just in case you are having issues with cookie:

Cookie need to be added to the headers like this:

```
Header:Cookie
Value:<cookie_name>=<cookie>
```

Also, if you are testing via Postman app from chrome, make sure to enable sending restricted headers (since "Cookie" is a restricted header, for more info see https://www.getpostman.com/docs/requests)